# how to create loading animation

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have many media elements in my application that are streamed via web. Sometimes I need to wait 2-3 seconds for that. That isn't a problem for me. The problem is that I don't know how to make some kind of animation of loading. I have an animated gif of loading bar but I don't know how to display it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a gif for it. There is a XAML Control *ProgressRing*. Bind it's *IsActive* property to a property which indicates that you are loading.

Something like:

```
public class DataService : BindableBase
{
    private bool _isLoading;

    public bool IsLoading 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _isLoading;
        }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isLoading, "IsLoading");
        }
    }

    public void MyMethodWhichTakesLongTime() 
    {
        IsLoading = true;

        // Do some time consumption

        IsLoading = false;
    }
}
```

For the XAML something like:

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}" 
              DataContext="{Binding MyDataService}" 
              Width="50" 
              Height="50" />
```

Thanks to the binding (and the BindableBase which comes from the standard MS Templates (otherwise you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)) the ProgressRing will automatically get active, when your dataservice is doing something.

Comment: cool that is what I've needed !! Big thanks

Answer (score 2):

ProgressBar is also available, which is the horizontal loading bar similar to Windows Phone 7

For an indeterminate progress bar, you can use

```
<ProgressBar Visibility="Visible" IsIndeterminate="True" />
```